Project tree in Matlab
I downloaded an open source project from the Matlab website. It has a lot of interconnected functions (about 40). I want to understand how it works in more detail, and to do this I would like to see if there is some way to build a project tree to see how the functions relate to each other and what the data flow is in the project.
Thank you!
From there I downloaded https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2917-calling-tree, but unfortunately, this is not what I need.
